# symbol for multiple regression

Tags: r, notation

In R, when we make regression models using `lm()`, we use the tilde symbol  `y ~ x1 + x2` to express a linear regression model of the form $y = \beta_{1}x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2}$.

To refer to different models in a research paper, I was using the tilde symbol `~` in written sentences to mitigate the cumbersome task of spelling out full equations with beta coefficients.  But it looks like the tilde symbol is not widely used outside of R code syntax.  Is it ok to use the tilde in prose with equations?  If not, is there a better symbol for prose that means the same thing as the tilde??

Comment: In mathematical notation, the tilde symbol is commonly used to mean "distributed as". For example $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ indicates that random variable $X$ has a normal distribution with the specified parameters. I think overloading this symbol in a paper as a shorthand for linear regression would be confusing.

Comment: Software notation and conventional statistical notation are often quite distinct and while that's true it is best in a paper to follow conventional statistical notation. Unless you're writing for the _R Journal_ it's best not to assume that everyone reading the journal concerned is fluent in R. (Creep can occur. I've noticed $*$ in student work to denote multiplication when mathematical convention usually just entails juxtaposition of multiplied terms or at most $\times$.)